# How to Create Context with Helper functions

Tags: react-native, expo, react-context

I have a Helper file with multiple functions, but I needed to have some "state" updates, I need to store some values and use them in various components.
I've had the idea of creating a `Context.Provider` but I cannot access the functions.
I was trying to acces the functions like `API.getSomething`.

```
    export const ApiContext = createContext();

export default function ApiProvider({ children }) {

    return (
        <ApiContext.Provider value={ api }>

            {children}
        </ApiContext.Provider>

    );
}

export function useApi() {

    const con = useContext(ApiContext);
    console.log("API CONTEXT {" + JSON.stringify(con, undefined, 2)+"}");   // This is returning "API CONTEXT {{}}"
    con.getSomething; // getSomething is not a function
    return { con };
}

const api = {

    getSomething : function () {

        console.log( "HAHAHA");
    },

}
```

I coudn't find anything about this.
Have someone tried this?
Is this possible? Or should I try another aproach?

Thanks in advance

PS.: I'm using Expo if it's relevant

Comment: Instead of accessing from useApi call it from a child component of ApiProvider

Comment: This isn't the problem here. I Want to know if someone already tried something like this, or if there are some better way of acessing a helper file

Comment: I tried a theme provider, i'm sure that this can be achieved with some tweaks https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/-themeprovider